# MVC3 Submit form in jQuery Mobile site

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Iv'e been searching for an answer for this all day and thought it was going to be a simple thing to do.

I have the following code populating a drop down box from the database it all works fine, the drop down is populated and the form auto submits after an article is selected, but it does not send a parameter back or tell the ViewResults action method which item was selected so I get an error as "id" in null. If I manually add a number for “id” to the URL string it all works fine.

Controller Methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var db = new MvcFourEntities();
    var query = db.Articles.Select(c => new { c.ArticleID, c.ArticleName });
    ViewBag.ArticleId = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ArticleID", "ArticleName", 0);
    return View(db.Articles.ToList());
}

public ViewResult Details(int id)
{          
    Article article = db.Articles.Single(a => a.ArticleID == id);
    return View(article);
}
```

Drop Down List in the View in two different forms, one to submit via jQuery and one not, neither pass a parameter:

jQuery submission:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })){

    @Html.DropDownList("ArticleID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ArticleId, "Please Select an Article")
}
```

Non jQuery submission:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" }))
{

@Html.DropDownList(
"ArticleID",
(SelectList)ViewData["Articles"],
"Please Select an Article",
    new
    {
        onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();"
    })
 }
```

I’ve been following the tutorial found here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists

Where am I gone wrong???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

In both calls to `Html.DropDownList` you are setting the name of the select as `ArticleID`. You need to change this to `id`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })){
                       // The first parameter has been changed from "ArticleID" to "id"
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)ViewBag.ArticleId, "Please Select an Article")
}
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) documentation.

Comment: If I change it to “id” I get “There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'id” and I never been able to understand MSDN documentation

Comment: Please see the example I've put in my answer

Answer (score 0):

A hack written by John Allers work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ArticleID").change(function () {
            var actionUrl = $('#TheForm').attr('action') + '/' + $('#ArticleID').val();
            $('#TheForm').attr('action', actionUrl);
            $('#TheForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```